# Where Are The Commando Droids In Revenge of the Sith?

Tags: star-wars

In the Clone Wars TV series, the commando droids are pretty common in battle, especially in the second half of the series. However, none are to be seen in Episode 3 even though they would make perfect sense given what the battle droids have to do in the film such as the battle of Kashyyyk and protecting the separatist council.

I realize out of universe the reason is that they hadn’t come up with them yet. But what about in universe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR : The BX-series of droid was prohibitively expensive to produce, and The Confederacy was running out of resources by Episode III.**

---

The [**BX-series Droid Commando**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/BX-series_droid_commando/Canon), often referred to as "Commando Droids", were the Confederacy's most advanced model of battle-droid. Seen on a few occasions near the end of [The Clone Wars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Clone_Wars), the BX Commando Droid was a unique prototype model designed for stealth & infiltration missions, possessed of a highly intelligent (and dynamic) intelligence as well as a streamlined body that could fit  under clonetrooper armor. BX pairs were often used as bodyguards for officials within the higher eschelons of [The Confederacy](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Confederacy_of_Independent_Systems/Canon).

[image]

However, due to the advanced technology used in their processors, the BX series droid required a prohibitive production cost - so much so that only a handful of the droids were ever produced.

It's quite likely that, by [The Battle of Coruscant](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Coruscant/Canon), very few (if any) of the BX series droids were still functional. Assuming a limited production run of 30 or less (which is about twice what we see on-screen in [Star Wars: The Clone Wars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_(TV_series))), it's doubtful that any would be available once the Seperatists had begun to run out of money & resources.

Comment: the separatists run out of money & resources?

Comment: It might be good to add a source referencing the Separatists' limited resources in Episode III.